# unable to get data from service using retrieve function in angular 2

Tags: angular

**Current Code:** I have successfully stored the data into the service using below function in my search page. `this.userService.saveLocationData(this.locationType);` and below code is in my service page.

```
saveLocationData(data:any){
      this.locationdata = data;
      console.log(this.locationdata);

  }
```

After i successfully navigate to the user page, i am not getting location data in my user component. I have used below code in my user component and inside constructor.

```
this.locationData = this.userService.retrieveLocationData();
```

and I have used retrieve function in my service page given below

```
retrieveLocationData(){
    console.log(this.locationdata);
      return this.locationdata;
  }
```

**Issue:** I am unable to get the location data in my user component. but i have saved in service using saveLocationData function. I have attached the screen shot represents navigation and before going to user component i have saved the location details. and i have checked in console and i got. But in my user component i didn't get the details of location.

[image]

Comment: are you sure you are getting the same instance of your userService in both places?

Comment: No, Actually in search component  I have saved location data in service, when navigate I am not getting the location data in user component.

Comment: Can you please add where you have provided your service and code of service?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving a *reference* to an object, and maybe that object is being modified during route changes. So when you fetch that *reference* from your service it just yields how it has changed.

Try making a copy of the object.

```
saveLocationData(data:any){
   this.locationdata= Object.assign({}, data);
   console.log(this.locationdata);
}
```

If your object contains deep references. You'll need to make a deep copy. Which can be done like this, but you'll loose any methods.

```
saveLocationData(data:any){
   this.locationdata= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));;
   console.log(this.locationdata);
}
```

When routes load lazy modules the services can get duplicates.

I have not tested this trick, but maybe you can catch duplicates via the service constructor.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService
     public constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() previousService: MyService) {
           if(previousService) {
                throw new Error('Service already loaded.');
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I am asking you given,  I will try above code. But I have dought is better we pass is location id to user component and  there we will get Data, can you please clarify which one is better option

Comment: It's better to not clone data. If you can get fresh data from the location ID then I would do that.

Comment: OK, i have passed to user and i got values. and i am facing difficulty when i am clicking 'Go back' button on browser. In home page i have slider. when i am return from user page to home using 'Go back' button slider not working. Can u help me is there any possibility. or it  is possible to refresh and go to home page when click  'Go back' button.

Comment: That's a different question. You should open a new question on stackoverflow. Provide clear details and sample code.